# XCODE SWIFT How do I execute code after a button is pressed, but in another file/class?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, grand-central-dispatch

I am using MapKit, and the user has the ability to add annotations.  They can tap on the screen, which prompts them if they want to add an annotation with a UIAlert, and If they say yes, it presents another view controller so the user can input information about the annotation, like the location name, description, etc. That view controller has a 'Done' BarButtonItem up top to confirm the information that they input, and create the annotation.

```
@IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        doneButtonHasBeenPressed = true
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The problem is, The annotation has to be created in my 'touchesEnded' function in the original view controller, that sent the user to the view controller where they input the annotation information, because that is where it gets the CLCoordinate2D from (using the touchesEnded).  It is in that same touchesEnded function where I send the user to that next view controller.  Here is the touchesEnded code and a helper function it uses:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: view)
        
        // Converts CGPoint coordinates and UIView to CLLocationCordinate2D (map coordinates) Remember to rename if addButtonPressed order of creation of annotation gets changed!
        let coordinatesTouchedToCreateAnnotation = mapView.convert(touchLocation, toCoordinateFrom: view)
        
        if userIsAllowedToAddAnnotation {
            
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm", message: "Are you sure you want to add a jump location here?", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
            let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            
            let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) { (action) in
                
                // Segue takes user to JumpSpotCreatorController to input information about the jump location
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CreateJumpSpot", sender: self)
                
                
                    if self.jumpSpotCreatorController.doneButtonHasBeenPressed == true {

                        self.jumpSpotCreatorController.doneButtonHasBeenPressed = false
                        self.createJumpSpotAnnotation(coordinatesDeterminedByTouch: coordinatesTouchedToCreateAnnotation)
                        self.userIsAllowedToAddAnnotation = false
                        self.tapToAddJumpSpotLabel.isHidden = true

                    }
                
                
                
            }
            alertController.addAction(noAction)
            alertController.addAction(yesAction)
            
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
}

// Force unwrap is okay because this will only be called if 'Done' button is pressed in the JumpSpotCreatorController, which mandates that those inputs not be nil.
func createJumpSpotAnnotation(coordinatesDeterminedByTouch: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    mapView.addAnnotation(JumpSpotAnnotation(name: jumpSpotCreatorController.nameTextField.text!, coordinate: coordinatesDeterminedByTouch, estimatedHeight: jumpSpotCreatorController.estimatedHeightTextField.text!, locationDescription: jumpSpotCreatorController.descripitionTextView.text, warnings: jumpSpotCreatorController.warningsTextView.text ?? "", image: jumpSpotCreatorController.jumpSpotImageView.image ?? UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "Image-1")))
}
```

As you can see, the block of code that creates the Annotation in the touchesEnded function (located right above where I add actions to the alertController, in case you can't find it.  It's about 4 lines), is executed immediately, as opposed to when I need it to be, which is once the 'Done' button is pressed in my other view controller (JumpSpotCreatorController).  I tried fixing that with the doneButtonHasBeenPressed variable, but it makes no difference (for obvious reasons).  How can I execute it only once that done button is pressed? I can't initialize the other view controller as an object in the main one (the one with touchesEnded is the main one) because it will create an infinite loop of references between the two view controllers.  Can DispatchQueue help in some way? I've researched it for hours but can't quite figure out how to apply it here.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: DispatchQueue is not relevant... in short, in the abstract, you need "another" class (or, something) which wrangles both these things.

Comment: @Fattie You mean like an intermediary class? One that reference both of them? Will that not cause another infinite loop?

Comment: cheers, I put in a simple answer which may help.

Comment: @Fattie Thanks! gonna take a minute and look at this, might ask another question unless I figure it out, just one thing, when you say I'm 'in' A, what do you mean by 'in'? is A a view controller?

Comment: yes "A" could be aview controller - or any piece of code!

Comment: What is `performSegue(withIdentifier: "CreateJumpSpot", sender: self)` doing? Are you pushing to a new controller? Are you presenting a new controller?

Comment: pushing to a new controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this --- each with pros and cons.

This approach uses the delegate / protocol pattern.

We define a protocol, which will allow classes to execute functions in their delegate classes:

```
// protocol / delegate pttern
protocol JumpSpotDelegate: class {
    func createJumpSpotAnnotation(_ name: String, estimatedHeight: String, locationDescription: String, warnings: String, image: UIImage?)
    func cancelAnnotation()
}
```

In the controller with your map view, we conform to that delegate:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, JumpSpotDelegate {
```

In `JumpSpotCreatorController`, we set up a `delegate` property:

```
class JumpSpotCreatorController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: JumpSpotDelegate?
```

When we navigate to the `JumpSpotCreatorController`, we assign self as its delegate:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // make sure we're acting on the correct segue
        if segue.identifier == "CreateJumpSpot", let vc = segue.destination as? JumpSpotCreatorController {
            // set the delegate in the JumpSpotCreatorController we're navigating to
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

In `JumpSpotCreatorController`, when Done button is tapped, we tell the map controller via the delegate function:

```
    delegate?.createJumpSpotAnnotation(name, estimatedHeight: estimatedHeight, locationDescription: description, warnings: warnings, image: img)
```

Here it is together. I added objects via `let` statements to write this... I expect you have them as `@IBOutlet` connections:

```
// protocol / delegate pttern
protocol JumpSpotDelegate: class {
    func createJumpSpotAnnotation(_ name: String, estimatedHeight: String, locationDescription: String, warnings: String, image: UIImage?)
    func cancelAnnotation()
}

class MapViewController: UIViewController, JumpSpotDelegate {
    
    // this will hold the touch point while we navigate to and back from the JumpSpotCreatorController
    var lastTouch: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    
    let mapView: MKMapView!
    
    var userIsAllowedToAddAnnotation = true
    let tapToAddJumpSpotLabel = UILabel()
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: view)
            
            // Converts CGPoint coordinates and UIView to CLLocationCordinate2D (map coordinates)
            // store in class property
            self.lastTouch = mapView.convert(touchLocation, toCoordinateFrom: view)
            
            if userIsAllowedToAddAnnotation {
                
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm", message: "Are you sure you want to add a jump location here?", preferredStyle: .alert)
                
                let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                
                let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) { (action) in
                    
                    // Segue takes user to JumpSpotCreatorController to input information about the jump location
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CreateJumpSpot", sender: self)
                    
                }
                alertController.addAction(noAction)
                alertController.addAction(yesAction)
                
                present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            } else {
                return
            }
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // make sure we're acting on the correct segue
        if segue.identifier == "CreateJumpSpot", let vc = segue.destination as? JumpSpotCreatorController {
            // set the delegate in the JumpSpotCreatorController we're navigating to
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }

    // called by Button action in JumpSpotCreatorController
    func createJumpSpotAnnotation(_ name: String, estimatedHeight: String, locationDescription: String, warnings: String, image: UIImage?) {
        // the coordinate parameter was stored in our class property "lastTouch"
        guard let lastTouch = self.lastTouch else {
            // self.lastTouch was not set!
            return
        }
        mapView.addAnnotation(JumpSpotAnnotation(name: name, coordinate: lastTouch, estimatedHeight: estimatedHeight, locationDescription: description, warnings: warnings, image: image ?? UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "Image-1")))
        
        self.userIsAllowedToAddAnnotation = false
        self.tapToAddJumpSpotLabel.isHidden = true

        // pop from JumpSpotCreatorController back to self
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    // I'm assuming you would also have a Cancel button?
    func cancelAnnotation() {
        self.lastTouch = nil
        // pop from JumpSpotCreatorController back to self
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

}

class JumpSpotCreatorController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: JumpSpotDelegate?

    let nameTextField = UITextField()
    let estimatedHeightTextField = UITextField()
    let descripitionTextView = UITextView()
    let warningsTextView = UITextView()
    let jumpSpotImageView = UIImageView()
    
    @IBAction func doneBtnTapped() {
        // presumably, you'll validate all these
        guard let name = nameTextField.text,
            let estimatedHeight = estimatedHeightTextField.text,
            let description = descripitionTextView.text,
            let warnings = warningsTextView.text,
            let img = jumpSpotImageView.image else {
                // notify user required fields were blank
                return
        }
        
        delegate?.createJumpSpotAnnotation(name, estimatedHeight: estimatedHeight, locationDescription: description, warnings: warnings, image: img)
    }
    
    @IBAction func cancelBtnTapped() {
        delegate?.cancelAnnotation()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the effort into your answer.  I have incorporated the code but am left with two questions:  the popViewController doesn't seem to work.  when I put the dismiss function in the cancelButton that works, but it doesn't work for doneButtonPressed for some  reason. why wouldn't popOver work? I tried changing the segue to popover but that asks for an anchor and idk what that is.  SECOND.  The only thing left confusing me is the weak var delegate in JumpSpotCreatorController.  Is that simply to access whichever VC is set as the delegate, to access the function?

Comment: Cont. ----- If so, what if multiple VCs need to have the delegate? Is that a problem (don't worry, this isn't a problem for my code, just curious).  Also, im assuming this will all work, but I need to have the popOver work to see my annotation finally created! So that's really all that needs fixing. EDIT: after going through the code again, I think I realized that in the prepareForSegue function, you included vc.delegate = self.  Is that why it works? The vc's delegate property is set to the JumpSpotDelegate protocol in JumpSpotCreatorController, then prepareForSegue applies it to self!

Comment: @Derek - in response to my comment above, you said you are *"pushing to a new controller"* ... so you should **pop** that controller off the navigation stack - ***not*** dismiss it. It also sound like you have a segue connected to your "Done" button in`JumpSpotCreatorController` ... if so, delete that segue, and just connect the `@IBAction` to the Done button.

Comment: sorry, saying pushing was misleading. Im new and sometimes interchange words when I shouldn't.  The transition type is present modally.  So what shouldI do to dismiss that? Or should I just change it to a push (show)?  Also, my Done button is already an IBAction.  No segue, so that's ok

Comment: @Derek - if you’re using a Present Modally segue to navigate to the view controller, then use `dismiss()` instead of `popViewController`

Comment: Strangely enough, it won't dismiss because my entire doneButtonPressed is not being executed.  Checked to make sure it's enabled, deleted it and reconnected it and everything. Circle next to the line is filled in. No idea why it won't trigger.  Even put a print statment in it, and nothing ever shows up in the debugger.  Any idea why this weird thing would happen?  Again, thanks so much for your help

Comment: nvm, figured it out

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right you are trying to get something like this:

```
Class A {
   weak var referenceToB: B?
   @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
      guard var referenceToB = referenceToB else {
          fatalError("referenceToB not set!")
      }
      referenceToB!.otherFunction()
   }
}
Class B {
   func otherFunction() {
      //stuff
   }
}
```

In your case, after you have instantiated your VC assign a reference to an object of the class containing the desired function.

Comment: its close, my A has a var reference to my B, but the buttonAction is IN B.  The problem is the function in A that segues to B, is the same function where the code lies that I need executed AFTER the buttonAction in B is pressed, and I can't shift that code to another function, it has to be in the one it's currently in

Comment: Well then you could create a double weak reference. A -> B and B -> A. Not very elegant but it should get the job down

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow 100% but would this help:

- button is tapped and you are in "A"
- "A" calls to B to do something, AND,
- "A" passes along a reference to itself

(that is to say, "add an argument" to that call in B, which is a variable of class "A".  let's say that variable is named "callMeWhenYou'reFinished")

- when "B" finishes doing what it has to do
- simply call callMeWhenYou'reFinished#WhateverFunction

... and away you go!

As a sort of "general programming issue" (forgetting about what is available in Swift, etc) you're just describing "a callback".  If I did follow you correctly, hope it helps!

---

Further:

It's perfectly ok to *have references* that are sort of circular.  (So, A knows about B and B is given a callback to something in A.)

Obviously, if you then by mistake make an infinite loop, that's an infinite loop.  But "accidentally making an infinite loop" has absolutely no connection to whether or not you have separate classes, references, etc.

Comment: Hey, I think I get what you are saying, but this goes back to my infinite loop problem.  In A, I already have an object of class B initialized, so I can't have A pass a reference of itself to B, because then they recursively call each other.  Unless I am misunderstanding what you are saying?

Comment: hi @derek , hmm, of course, obviously, looking at my example: you wouldn't "AGAIN" call to B from A#WhateverFunction.  that would then loop forever.  But there's no problem with having the reference back to "A" (even if, as it happens "A is holding B")

Comment: thank you again, Im just trying to reread all the logic you said and understand it.  One problem im thinking, is that the function I'm calling in B is an IBAction (BarButtonItem), and it isn't called automatically by A, A simply segues me to the view controller, so is it still possible to pass a reference to A in there? Also, the function in A that segues me to B, is touchesEnded, so Im not sure exactly how that would work. The segue relies on a touch and then a selection of Yes in a UIAlert. Sorry if my code seems so confusing, trust me it makes sense to me as the coder lol. and again thanks

Comment: can you put the "FOUIR LINES OF CODE" in a SEPARATE function ??!

Comment: Nope! haha maybe that is where this is so confusing.  It must stay where it is, because it relies the 'touches' parameter of touchesEnded.  It uses this to determine where on the screen the user tapped, and converts the CGPoint to a CLLocationCoordinate2D, which I then use as the coordinates for the annotation that the user is creating.  sorry for any confusion.  If it helps, I changed the 4 lines of code into one line, just calling a function.  The function still uses the 'touches' parameter though, and must remain in the 'touchesEnded' function

Comment: hi @derek hmm, I don't see why you couldn't just make a note ofd the CLLocation and use it any time you wish ????

Comment: also @derek - whetever it is you do on the touch down ... just **wait until** the touches ended, and, do it all from there !!  no ?!

Comment: hmmm, I don't think that can work, but maybe I am wrong.  I don't believe CLLocation has anything to do with this.  I am currently working on a restructure work around that I thought of, will update once it's done.  again i really appreciate you helping so much